# AspNetCore - .xproj output path

Tags: c#, asp.net, msbuild, dnx, .xproj

I have been trying to step through some of the open source MVC/ASP.NET core code, but each time I stumble across some new project, after doing a `git clone`, I need to edit `.xproj` file to change the following output

```
<OutputPath Condition="'$(OutputPath)'=='' ">..\..\artifacts\bin\</OutputPath>
```

to

```
./bin/
```

Otherwise I get the following error

```
Severity: Error
Code:
Description:
C:\Users\lndco\Documents\GitHub\RazorBlog\src\RazorBlog\error 
CS0006: Metadata file
'C:\Users\lndco\Documents\GitHub\RazorBlog\Mvc
\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json
\bin\Debug\netstandard1.6\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json.dll' 
could not be found    
Project: RazorBlog
File: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets
```

Using VS 2015 Update 3

Why is MsBuild not figuring out that the output of the referenced assembly is `..\..\artifacts\bin\`?

## Files:

### global.json

```
{
  "projects": [
    "src",
    "test",
    "Mvc/src",

  ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"
  }
}
```

### AspNetCore poroject.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },

    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Forget about the concept of xproj and project.json. Install VS2017 and migrate all such to latest .NET Core SDK and MSBuild project format, then you won't waste your time on the past.

Comment: Will give a try thanks!